# Using modulus/loop and placing in every 5th position

Tags: php

I've given myself many hours trying to figure this one out - no luck, so I've come here for some help.

How would I go about using the php modulus operator and looping though an array but placing the array values in every 5th position (see picture below)

The "..." will be replaced from a mysql query array.

**Query sample:**

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, username, volume, name, content, image, cssanimate, group_name FROM table_1 ");
```

Hopefully this picture explains:
[image]

**Array sample:**
    $my_array = array("Tesla", "BMW", "Ford", "Jeep");

**Some code:**

```
$counter = 0;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $counter++;
    if(($counter % 5 == 0) || $counter==1 ) { 

    }

}
```

A help is appreciated :)

Comment: Hint: array having 4 index , multiple with 5 then use conditions.

Comment: @devpro thank you for the reply! I'm not sure I understand your hint/comment....

Comment: i have shared an example, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One Solution:**

You can modify your code as like that:

```
<?php
$my_array = array("Tesla", "BMW", "Ford", "Jeep");
$totalCount = count($my_array); // get the total count of your array
$iteration = $totalCount*5; // multiply as per your iteration

$newArray = array(); // initialize an array
$incArr = 0; // increment for your value's array
for ($i=1; $i <= $iteration; $i++) { 
    if(($i % 5 == 0) ) {  // at every fifth index
        $newArray[] = $my_array[$incArr]; // store actual value 
        $incArr++;      
    }   
    else{
        $newArray[] = "..."; // store if not a 5th value
    }
}
?>
```

**Result:**

```
<?php
$number = 1;
foreach ($newArray as $key => $value) {
    echo $number.") ".$value."<br/>";
    $number++;
}
?>
```

**[Sandbox:](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/828d22c9345bb6a35f25ca8b821f1fc0bb5badc3)**

Should be printed as:

```
1) ...
2) ...
3) ...
4) ...
5) Tesla
6) ...
7) ...
8) ...
9) ...
10) BMW
11) ...
12) ...
13) ...
14) ...
15) Ford
16) ...
17) ...
18) ...
19) ...
20) Jeep
```